# Bind A key using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery

I am trying to bind a key combination Ctrl+t with some event, so if i press Ctrl+t in my application it should go to specified url How can i do it using Jquery ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the jQuery HotKeys plugin:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/hotkeys

Update:

Added example

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl+t', function(event){ alert('Ctrl t pressed')});

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes i have downloaded that plugin and my code is follows :                     jQuery(document).bind('keypress',  'ctr+t',function (evt){ 
  alert('ctrl+t is pressed');
  return false
  }); But this code binds each and every key in my keyboard , not only ctrl+t , so whats wrong with the code??

Comment: @Hussy, you're missing an 'l' in the first `ctrl`, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very simply with `keydown`, `event.which` and `event.ctrlKey`. These are normalized by jQuery, so you don't need to fuss with  sorting out cross-browser stuff.

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) { // or whatever selector
    if (event.ctrlKey && (event.which === 84)) {
        window.location = 'http://example.com'; // or whatever url
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var isCtrl = false;
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 17) isCtrl = false;
}).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 17) isCtrl = true;
    if (e.which == 84 && isCtrl == true) {
        window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self', 'resizable,location,menubar,toolbar,scrollbars,status');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function test(evt){
          var keyCode = (evt.which?evt.which:(evt.keyCode?evt.keyCode:0))
            if(keyCode==116)
                window.location.href='your redirection';
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="Text" onkeypress=" test(event);"
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: -1 This won't work, because `test` is in the wrong scope. You include `hotkeys.js` but don't use it. You're suggesting jQuery 1.3.2 -- the current version is 1.6.1. You're doing unnecessary normalisation.